# Eclipse 4-10 64bit: Cannot resolve SWT library

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I try to get started with Eclipse 4-10 and SWT, but importing the SWT Library 
 in the java project doesn't work.

Here is what I did:

- Download Win 64bit Version of Eclipse 2018-12 and SWT library from here:
  https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.10-201812060815/
- use the Eclipse internal Installer to download and install "SWT Designer" with all it's dependencies from 2018-12 - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2018-12
- import the SWT-library-zip-file to the workspace via "File"->"Import"->"Existing projects into workspace"...
- create a new java project, called testproject
- get to testprojects "Properities"->"Java Build Path"->Tab "Projects"->Select "Classpath"->"Add"->select the org.eclipse.swt
- Create an Application Window in my testproject via "create  new visual classes"->"SWT"->"Application Window", called testwindow

But the import statements in the testwindow.java still show "the import org.eclipse cannot be resolved".

The setup process is according to the official eclipse site: https://www.eclipse.org/swt/eclipse.php

I use Windows 10 64bit, eclipse and SWT are both 64bit-versions too.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: In case you have a `module-info.java` file, delete it.

Comment: Did you add "Application window" by following 'WindowBuilder'-> 'SWT Designer'-> 'SWT'

Comment: Thanks, that solved the error! Maybe you could give a small explanation or post a link why `module-info.java` interfere with the functionality of the library-resolving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you have a **`module-info.java`** file in the default package, **delete it**.

Having a `module-info.java` file enables the optional use of the [Java Platform Module System (JPMS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) which requires to specify all required modules.

Instead of deleting `module-info.java` you can also:

1. In the *Java Build Path* move the *org.eclipse.swt* project from the *Classpath* to the *Modulepath*
2. In `module-info.java` add the line `requires org.eclipse.swt;`